# How do I Install Flash Player 10 without Adobe Download Manager?

Tags: firefox, flash, bloatware

How do I get Flash Player 10 (on Firefox) without installing the Adobe Download Manager?

Comment: Perhaps related if you're looking for EXE/MSI download for Flash Player 11.3/10.3: http://superuser.com/questions/436870/where-to-download-flash-player-newest-version-for-offline-installation/436871#436871

Answer (score 9):

The important bit is to not allow the download manager (Adobe DLM) to run, but instead click the link where it says 'If it does not start, click here to download'.

Comment: Note: The link now is to "troubleshooting information", and doesn't seem to offer the link to the installer anywhere (that I could find). The instructions from @Molly7244 below seem to work still.

Comment: There is currently (2010-06-22) a direct download link for the installer at the bottom of that troubleshooting page.

Comment: As of 2010-08-09 the "If it does not start, click here" link goes to a page that no longer has the direct download link.  I've used that link in the past, so I know what it looks like. But it's definitely gone now.  Anyone have up-to-date instructions to avoid DLM?  FYI, the fpdownload.adobe.com links in the other responses do still work.

Comment: As of 2011-03-28: Click on the "Click here for troubleshooting information.", then click on: "Troubleshoot Flash Player installation | Windows", there you can select "Download Flash Player with the manual installer" and then you can install it without the download manager.

Comment: -1. Answer needs updating.

Comment: @HaydnWVN This adobe “help” page(
http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/installation-problems-flash-player-windows.html ) has the links at the bottom, and as of Dec 2014 those are working. (interestingly still macromedia.com domains. What is dead will never die™... =)

— and just in case, [if someone is looking for hassle-free adobe-reader](ftp://ftp.adobe.com/pub/adobe/reader/win/11.x/).

Comment: Still, the answer needs updating to include these links. It is incomplete without these comments (thanks for including the link Fronker) - making the answer below (from qroberts) much more accurate and helpful.

Answer (score 6):

Firefox
http://fpdownload.adobe.com/get/flashplayer/current/install_flash_player.exe

Internet Explorer
http://fpdownload.adobe.com/get/flashplayer/current/install_flash_player_ax.exe

***Note**: Just add _ax to the file name and it will download the activex version for Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 5):

Use Adobe's public ftp site to download without the download manager **DLM**

For example, flash is here

**ftp://ftp.adobe.com/pub/adobe/flash/**

and acrobat reader is here

**ftp://ftp.adobe.com/pub/adobe/acrobatreader/**

Then simply choose version and operating system to get to the actual files

Comment: Best answer by far

Answer (score 4):

Version 10.1: [Direct download here](http://fpdownload.adobe.com/get/flashplayer/current/install_flash_player_ax.exe)

You need to shut down IE and/or FF, etc. when you install it. In my case I had to reboot for changes to take effect.

I think you have to use the DLM, but make sure you are still running firefox, wait for it to download. When you are asked t close firefox, search on your computer for recently changed files (name may be different): install_flash_player_64bit.exe (it's in a temp folder). Copy this to a different directory. You now have a standalone installer file. I tried opening the DLM installer w/ 7zip, but the contents are encrypted, so this was the easiest way.

Comment: The above link works for IE (the "active x") version, not for Firefox.

Answer (score 2):

http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/

http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/otherversions/

Comment: Okay I didn't look enough :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is the blog that explains very well how to install correct version of Flash for IE or Firefox:

http://www.techerator.com/2010/07/how-to-install-adobe-flash-player-without-installing-adobes-dlm-download-manager-browser-plugin/

Answer (score 1):

Direct downloads:

http://filehippo.com/download_flashplayer_ie/

http://filehippo.com/download_flashplayer_firefox/

Answer (score 1):

It seems that those sneaky direct download links are simply at the very bottom of the general ["installation problems"](https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/installation-problems-flash-player-windows.html) Help page

Here's a screenshot to help you scrolling..
[image: imgur screenshot]