# Where to download Flash Player for offline installation?

Tags: flash-player

I can't find Flash Player download link which will give me the full EXE/MSI file, not the tiny downloader which downloads data from the internet.

What's the proper download site for this?

Comment: See also http://superuser.com/questions/311763/where-can-i-find-a-stand-alone-flash-player-install?rq=1

Answer (score 82, accepted):

**Edit 2017:**
The installers are now at http://www.adobe.com/products/flashplayer/distribution5.html

**Edit 2016:**

It seems that the link below does no longer give access to offline installers :(

---

original answer:

### Download Adobe Flash Player 16 / 13 / 11.2 full **offline** standalone installers (MSI/EXE) for Internet Explorer / other browsers:

http://www.adobe.com/products/flashplayer/distribution3.html

I've contacted Adobe because I was completely unable to install Flash with the 900kb installer-downloaders which always flood me with strange errors (and delete themselves from the run location! so you can't launch the installer-downloader after failure, have to re-download it), and they sent me this link.

Comment: For a long time I've been downloading the latest version of the full installers for the Adobe Flash Player with the [FileHippo](http://filehippo.com) software update service.

Comment: This question was not about debug version, but thank you for sharing a link.

Comment: BTW, the debug version of standalone flashplayers are available at: http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html

Comment: This [adobe “help” page](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/installation-problems-flash-player-windows.html) also has the links at the bottom, and as of Dec 2014 those are working. (interestingly still macromedia.com domains. What is dead will never die™... =)

Comment: `This page and the download links will be decommissioned on January 22nd, 2016.` the site now says.

Comment: Adobe will soon no longer freely make the full downloadable version of the flash installer available. An account will be needed: "will be replaced by a new Adobe Flash Player distribution portal that will require a valid distribution license to access". When this happens people will either have to signup for a throw-away account, get it from BT, or uninstall flash when the next big vulnerability hits.

Comment: yes, it doesn't work anymore, try gras-double answer.

Answer (score 20):

For a long time, I've been taking the offline installers from this page: [Installation problems for Windows 7 and older](https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/installation-problems-flash-player-windows.html#main-pars_text_4) (already mentioned in a comment by Fronker).

The links are always up-to-date, and it lets me get all plugin architectures (as of today [ActiveX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ActiveX),
[NPAPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NPAPI) and
[PPAPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NPAPI#PPAPI)).
The links are near the bottom, under the **Still having problems?** heading.

The above instructions are for Windows, but the same approach works for Mac OS X.  Here's the Adobe help page with the offline installer links at the bottom: [Installation Problems – Mac](https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/installation-problems-flash-player-mac.html#main-pars_text_4).  This Adobe help forum page is also helpful: [How to perform a "clean install" of Flash Player in Mac OS X](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1267823).

Comment: Extra clafifiction: The Links are under “still having problems”

Comment: thank you. I knew about the projectors, but this is exactly what I was looking for :D . I think that this deserves more votes - or at least to get its own question. This is valuable information.

Answer (score 15):

Adobe has decommissioned the Distribution page, but here's another method that still works for now:

On the standard installation page https://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/ the "Install Now" button links to the download page `https://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/download/?installer=...`, you should append `&standalone=1` to the end, then it'll let you download the normal standalone offline installer.

P.S. Don't forget to disable "Optional offer" before copying the link.

Comment: This is the only relevant solution as of Jan 2017.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as of Apr 2017

Comment: Tried today and doesn't work, sadly.

Comment: I got `The page you requested could not be found on our web site.`

Comment: @hmj6jmh, works for me. You could try again or use the solution by Gras Double, it works too. I've also added direct links now.

Comment: What works for you? Why would I try again when I have found the direct source of all installers, without an account, and have successfully installed the latest version?

Comment: It may have been prudent to actually point people to the answer that Gras Double authored, rather than update _your_ answer based upon what he posted and merely thanking them afterwards.

Comment: @Run5k: His answer doesn't contain direct links, that's why I decided to post them. But I agree that injecting them to my higher voted answer was probably a bit not fair, even though I gave credit to him. So I've moved the links to a [separate answer](https://superuser.com/a/1268421/285720) now.

Answer (score 5):

If you download the flash player cab file for Microsoft System Center/SCCM, extract the xml file from the it, then you'll see the msi file listed in the xml file. There's a link for the activex installer and also the Mozilla/firefox/netscape plugin.

http://www.adobe.com/licensing/distribution/strategies/sms.html

Answer (score 4):

Sorry for bad English...
Most old answers doesn't work in 2016. So...
Here are **direct** download links to *Adobe Flash Player* **Offline Installer** for *Windows* (flash version 24.0.0.186, from **2016-12-20**):
NPAPI (Firefox): https://fpdownload.adobe.com/get/flashplayer/pdc/24.0.0.186/install_flash_player.exe 
PPAPI (Opera/Chromium): https://fpdownload.adobe.com/get/flashplayer/pdc/24.0.0.186/install_flash_player_ppapi.exe 
ActiveX (InternetExplorer): https://fpdownload.adobe.com/get/flashplayer/pdc/24.0.0.186/install_flash_player_ax.exe 
Uninstaller: https://fpdownload.macromedia.com/get/flashplayer/current/support/uninstall_flash_player.exe

Comment: This worked today (2017-07-16).

Comment: Today (2017-08-04) the links work if you change the version number part. So 24.0.0.186 must be changed to 26.0.0.137 which is the current version. Using the links as-is results in a 404 error.

Answer (score 3):

@GrasDouble [provides](https://superuser.com/a/870188) the link to the page where you can find the installers.

Here are **direct links** from there to save you a click:
[Flash Player for Internet Explorer - ActiveX](https://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/flashplayer/latest/help/install_flash_player_ax.exe)
[Flash Player for Firefox - NPAPI](https://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/flashplayer/latest/help/install_flash_player.exe)
[Flash Player for Opera and Chromium-based browsers - PPAPI](https://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/flashplayer/latest/help/install_flash_player_ppapi.exe)

Comment: Thanks, since 2020 I couldn't find any installer anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the link provided by jakub.g––http://www.adobe.com/products/flashplayer/distribution5.html. Though I logged in with my 'trial' account, I got `No Adobe Flash Player distribution license found for this user. Please apply by visiting http://www.adobe.com/products/players/flash-player-distribution.html`. They require all kinds of information to get an account.

Oddly enough, on the normal distribution site––https://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/otherversions/, there is a link at the bottom––`Archived Flash Player versions`: https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/archived-flash-player-versions.html, that actually has the full installers for up to the current version. The downloaded archive had every installer for every platform. I installed the one for `OS X` from the command line. `sudo installer -verboseR -dumplog -pkg "Install Adobe Flash Player.pkg" -target /`. Much faster and more reliable than the GUI.

Answer (score 1):

Now in 2021 that Adobe has cut off all the downloads, the only place I can find old versions is at: https://archive.org/details/flashplayerarchive

You'll also need an old web browser version to go with that. I'd suggest you look at the Firefox archives: https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/ with a version less than 85, though to make life easier, I'd go with version 51.0.1 as there are no special steps needed to re-enable npapi.

Keep in mind that both of these software packages are unsupported, and has security flaws that are documented, and there are very likely exploits out on the net.

Answer (score 1):

None of the solutions here will work today anymore in the year 2023.
Even if you find the original installer anywhere, it will be useless because Microsoft has blocked the installation on Windows 10 and 11. All that you get will be this stupid error:

[image: Adobe Flash Player Installation Error]

This message is a lie. This screenshot is from a Windows 11 where Adobe Flash has never been installed. So you even get wrong information from the installer.

The reason why Flash has been retired is because of security issues. This is sad, I liked Flash very much.

But this does not mean that there is no solution. I wrote a software "PTBSync" which among other features displays a desktop calendar where the user can select a Flash Clock and other utilities to be displayed on the desktop. Therefore Adobe Flash must be installed.

So my software runs a local flash file which does not mean any security risk.

I extracted the Flash files and the registry entries from an intact installation and offer it on my homepage. You can download a ZIP file with the latest Flash version and copy the files to your disk and double click the .REG file. So you get Flash running on your Windows 10 or 11 within one minute.

Here you see the flash clock on my Windows 11 desktop:

[image: Adobe Flash running on Windows 11]

You can download the manual Adobe Flash Installation [from my homepage](https://netcult.ch/elmue/Install_Adobe_Flash_Player_on_Windows_10_and_11.htm)